# java persistence with dates

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have problems executing an orm query in an oracle database, when one of its parameters is a date string

this is the query :

```
<named-native-query name="MyProject.QueryName"
    result-set-mapping="MyProject.QueryNameMapping">
    <query>
       <![CDATA[
          select 
            bnumber,
            to_timestamp(chargestart) as chargestart,
            reportedduration, 
            cost, 
            typeofcall
          from mydb@mytable t
          where t.answertime is not null
          and t.directorynumber = :mdn
          and to_date(substr(servicestart,1,17),'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date(:startdate, 'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS')
          and to_date(substr(servicestop,1,17), 'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS') <  to_date(:todate,    'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS')
          order by servicestart
       ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="MyProject.QueryNameMapping">
    <column-result name="bnumber"/>
    <column-result name="chargestart"/>
    <column-result name="reportedduration"/>
    <column-result name="cost"/>
    <column-result name="typeofcall"/>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

The inputs are

- XMLGregorianCalendar startDate
- XMLGregorianCalendar endDate
- String mdn (this is a phone number)

This is my code :

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

try{
    GregorianCalendar start = startDate.toGregorianCalendar();
    start.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1); // because of timezone +1 
    GregorianCalendar end = endDate.toGregorianCalendar();
    end.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1); // because of timezone +1

    list = ((Session) em.getDelegate()).getNamedQuery("HotelskoResenjeWS.vratiListingZaBroj")
                    .setParameter("mdn", account.getMdn())
                    .setParameter("startdate", (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss").format(start.getTime() ) ))
                    .setParameter("todate", (   new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss").format(  end.getTime() ) ))
                    .list();
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The problem occurs for input values with hours in the afternoon (12-23). I can see them in the database when i manually run a query with the same inputs, but when i try to retrieve them via Java code, it returns an empty list of objects read from the database.

To add to the confusion, the code works for input values with hours before noon. (00-12)

Please help.

Comment: huh? you have JPA named queries and then throw away portability and hack into Hibernate API calls?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. When i tried to JPA my way through reading the database rows, the dates i was getting would all have their time set to 00:00:00, which was wrong for each and every one of them. I banged my head about it for a week, and this was the only solution that fixed.

Comment: which is where you look in the LOG and see the SQL invoked. Maybe you did that, but the end result should have been raising a bug on your JPA provider ...

Comment: I did all of those things. No reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply pass the calendar instances as parameter and use them as they are without that formatting in the query itself:

```
and to_date(substr(servicestart,1,17),'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS') >= :startdate
and to_date(substr(servicestop,1,17), 'dd.mm.rr HH24:MI:SS') <  :todate
```

and the java part:

```
list = ((Session) em.getDelegate()).getNamedQuery("HotelskoResenjeWS.vratiListingZaBroj")
                    .setParameter("mdn", account.getMdn())
                    .setParameter("startdate", start, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                    .setParameter("todate", end, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                    .list();
```